# Setting parse action for operatorPrecedence in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

Is there another way of setting a parse action than directly in `operatorPrecedence` for pyparsing?

I'd like to define `action` in this example somewhere else.

```
expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition, [
    (not_, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, action),
    (and_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, action),
    (or_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, action),
])
```

I tried `and_.setParseAction(action)`, but this doesn't get the 2 condition arguments. `expr.setParseAction(action)` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [wise man once said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection), "Every programming problem can be solved by adding another level of indirection."  And so I give you the OperParseActionHolder class:

```
class OperParseActionHolder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize with a do-nothing parse action
        self.fn = lambda s,l,t: None

    def __call__(self, s, l, t):
        return self.fn(s,l,t)

notParseAction = OperParseActionHolder()
andParseAction = OperParseActionHolder()
orParseAction = OperParseActionHolder()

expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition, [
    (not_, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, notParseAction),
    (and_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, andParseAction),
    (or_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, orParseAction),
])


# before calling expr.parseString
notParseAction.fn = theRealParseActionToCallForNot
andParseAction.fn = theRealParseActionToCallForAnd
orParseAction.fn = theRealParseActionToCallForOr
```

Comment: BTW, the name "operatorPrecedence" is being replaced with the more descriptive "infixNotation", which describes what kind of expression you are building, which just happens to structure the results according to the defined precedence of operations.

Comment: ;-) Fair enough comment. I just didn't want to scatter my parse actions which can be extensive together with the grammar... but I take the wise man's advice...